# Probabilstic Method

Tags: probability-theory, probabilistic-method

This is a question in the book Probabilistic Method by Noga Alon.
The question is from the chapter second moment.
Show that there is a positive constant $c$ such that the folowing holds. For any $n$ reals $a_{1}, a_{2},....,a_{n}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} (a_{i})^{2} =1 $ if $b_{1}, b_{2}....b_{n}$ is a $ \{-1,1\} $ random vector obtained by choosing each $b_{i}$ randomly, independently with uniform distribution to be either $-1$ or $1$ then
$Pr |\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}b_{i}a_{i}| \leq 1 | \geq c $

Comment: The average of the quantity inside the absolute value is zero and it's second moment is $1$. Can it be larger in value than $1$ always?

Comment: i had worked that out. However we have to use something more to solve this question, I believe somewhere we will have to use the fact that the maximum value of the quantity will be $\sqrt{n}$ and there are at max  $2^{n}$ distinct values taken by the quantity